# Disabling ButtonField when BoundField is zero

Tags: c#, sql-server, gridview, webforms

I have this `GridView` that fills on the `Page_Load`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
    GridView1.DataSource = actBO.BuscarActividades();
    GridView1.DataBind();
  }
}
```

---

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="ID" Visible="False" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Class" HeaderText="Class" /> 
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Day" HeaderText="Day" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Time" HeaderText="Time" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Vacants" HeaderText="Vacants" />          

            <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" HeaderText="Book" Text="Book"/>

        </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

Where column "Vacants" shows an `int` (it represents the amount of vacant booking spaces in a class).

Every row will have a button to book a specific class. I need to place a condition for when the field "Vacants" is zero, so the "Book" button will be disabled.

So far this is what it looks like: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVVUs.png).

As you can see, I need the button to be disabled when there are no more vacants. It shouldn't be able to be clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do so, you must register `OnRowDataBound` event. More explanations can be found in [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="ID" Visible="False" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Class" HeaderText="Class" /> 
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Day" HeaderText="Day" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Time" HeaderText="Time" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Vacants" HeaderText="Vacants" />          
            <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" HeaderText="Book" Text="Book"/>
        </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>


protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // get your button via the column index; ideally you could use template field and put your own button inside
        var button = e.Row.Cell[5].Controls[0] as Button;
        int vacant = 0;
        var vacantVal = int.TryParse(e.Row.Cell[4].Text, out vacant);
        if (button != null)
        {
            button.Enabled = vacant > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.